# How Can I Remove Duplicate Rows from CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have CSV file that looks like this:

```
account, name, email,
123, John, dsfs@email.com
123, John, dsfs@email.com
1234, Alex, ala@email.com
```

I need to remove duplicate rows.I try to do it like this:

```
$inputHandle = fopen($inputfile, "r");
$csv = fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1000, ",");

$accounts_unique = array();

$accounts_unique = array_unique($csv);  

print("<pre>".print_r($accounts_unique, true)."</pre>");
```

But I get in print_r only first headers row.
What needs to be done in order to make sure I 
1. I clean the CSV file from duplicate rows
2. I can make some list of those duplicates (maybe store them in another CSV?)

Comment: `fgetcsv` only gets one row. If you need all rows, you need to loop.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution, but it requires a lot of memory if file is really big.

```
$lines = file('csv.csv');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents(implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I need some more logic there...How can I make note of duplicate rows?

Comment: and btw, the duplicates are not removed when I run this

Comment: @sectus -- just suggesting that you might want to use `array_keys(array_flip())` or `array_flip(array_flip())` rather than `array_unique()`, given the significant performance difference. @Alex -- `array_diff_key($before, $after)` will give you the dropped item keys if you used `array_unique()` or `array_flip(array_flip())`.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, changed answer (added `$lines = `)

Answer (score 1):

I would go this route, which will be faster than array_unique:

```
$inputHandle = fopen($inputfile, "r");
$csv = trim(fgetcsv($inputHandle, 1000, ","));
$data = array_flip(array_flip($csv)); //removes duplicates that are the same
$dropped = array_diff_key($csv, $data); //Get removed items.
```

Note -- `array_unique()` and `array_flip(array_flip())` will only match for duplicate lines that are *exactly* the same.

Updated to include information from my comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to loop the data from the CSV anyway I think it would be best to do something like this.

```
$dataset = array();
foreach($line as $data){
    $dataset[sha1($data)] = $data;
}
```